# IntegrityError at /admin/products/shop/add/ products_shop.product_id may not be NULL

Tags: python

```
class Product(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)        
    shops = models.ManyToManyField('shop', blank=True)
    default_shop = models.ForeignKey('shop',   related_name='shop_products', null=True, blank=True)
    categories = models.ManyToManyField('Category', blank=True)
    default = models.ForeignKey('Category', related_name='default_category', null=True, blank=True)


def image_upload_to_shop(instance, filename):
name = instance.name
slug = slugify(name)
basename, file_extension = filename.split(".")
new_filename = "%s-%s.%s" %(slug, instance.id, file_extension)
return "products/%s/shop/%s" %(slug, new_filename)


class shop(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=image_upload_to_shop, blank=True)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=120)

      def __unicode__(self):
      return self.name
```

i have a model named product, shop and categories...etc
all the above code is working fine if i have product and shop model in seperate project  ..but when i add categories  and other stuff it shows me this error while adding a new shop

```
IntegrityError at /admin/products/shop/add/
products_shop.product_id may not be NULL
```

Comment: Did you previously have an extra field called `product` in your `shop` model? Did you migrate your changes after you change it?

Comment: yes firstly i did this with foreignkey ..like prdouct as foriegn key in shop model ,,,

Comment: Thanx.....now .i did migrate...its working now :)